# How do you find a url behind an html submit button?

Tags: python, html

This may be a stupid question as I am not familiar with html at all. How does one find a url behind an input type submit button.

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$content$search" value="Search" onclick="return      searchContinue(this);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$content$search&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_content_search">
```

I am just not familiar to find the required url to trigger the submit action. I am trying to write a script in python that will trigger the submit action.

Comment: The url will be in the action attribute of the form. ```<form action="demo_form/" method="post">```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URl will be in `<form action="/example.php">`

Example:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/submit.php">
<input type="text" name="Name"></input>
<input type=submit"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know how to deal with a case where it seems like not all the information is given in the form action field?

Specifically, I am trying to find the URL to a search button on a French lyrics website (paroles.net); the HTML has <form class="mlm" action="/search" method="post" id="search-form-round">, in other words, I would think the URL is _paroles.net/search_, and that is indeed the URL I find when I search for a term on that website. But I could not use that URL to search directly on that website; I cannot type _paroles.net/search/Paradise_ to search for "Paradise".

Answer (score 3):

Address is in `<form action="some_url">` .

If there is no `action` then form use current page address.

Comment: what if the button is running a js function?

Comment: @tim then you have to manually find this js code and analyze it to find address. There is no universal method for do it. Only if you use Selenium to control web browser then Python can click button which will run JS and load new page - and you don't have to search URL. But it is different method and OP asked for something different.